# GDAL build from source throwing OpenSSL errors on Ubuntu

Tags: gdal, ubuntu

I'm trying to get GDAL installed/up to date on my Ubuntu machine, and I can't seem to get it to work properly. I've been following this process: https://milkator.wordpress.com/2014/05/06/set-up-gdal-on-ubuntu-14-04/, which is the same as the one described in [Installing gdal 1.9.0 on linux ubuntu server 10.04?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21728/how-can-i-install-gdal-1-9-0-on-my-linux-ubuntu-server-10-04), but when I run `make`, I get all of these undefined reference errors that all seem to have to do with OpenSSL (at end of question).

I've tried installing openssl, but it's already on the latest version. I've been able to find similar errors elsewhere, but they haven't been very helpful or related (e.g. https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/COOK-1406).

I also haven't been able to get up and running from the ubuntugis ppa in the way that I want. I've been able to install gdal-bin, but `gdalinfo --version` returns `GDAL 1.10.1, released 2013/08/26` (current version is now 1.11.2), which would be less of a problem if it also included the gdal python scripts, like gdal2tiles.py, which are what I'm ultimately after a working version of. They're not in /usr/bin, and I'm not sure where else to look.

I'm honestly not sure whether this is a problem with make, gdal, my machine, or something else entirely.

Errors from `make`:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/MY_USER_FOLDER/sourceBuild/gdal-1.11.2/apps'
/bin/bash /home/MY_USER_FOLDER/sourceBuild/gdal-1.11.2/libtool --mode=link  g++  gdalinfo.lo commonutils.lo  /home/MY_USER_FOLDER/sourceBuild/gdal-1.11.2/libgdal.la -o gdalinfo
libtool: link: g++ .libs/gdalinfo.o .libs/commonutils.o -o .libs/gdalinfo  /home/MY_USER_FOLDER/sourceBuild/gdal-1.11.2/.libs/libgdal.so -L/usr/lib -L/home/MY_USER_FOLDER/anaconda3/lib -lgeos_c /home/MY_USER_FOLDER/anaconda3/lib/libsqlite3.so -lodbc -lodbcinst /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so -lxerces-c -ljasper -lnetcdf /home/MY_USER_FOLDER/anaconda3/lib/libhdf5.so /usr/lib/libmfhdfalt.so /usr/lib/libdfalt.so -lgif /home/MY_USER_FOLDER/anaconda3/lib/libjpeg.so /home/MY_USER_FOLDER/anaconda3/lib/libpng15.so -lpq -lpthread -lrt -lpcre /home/MY_USER_FOLDER/anaconda3/lib/libxml2.so -lm -lz -ldl  -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/MY_USER_FOLDER/anaconda3/lib
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_new@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_get_cert_store@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_check_private_key@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_num_locks@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `ENGINE_by_id@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `ERR_get_error@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_set_locking_callback@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_use_certificate_file@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `TLSv1_method@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `ENGINE_free@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_new@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_load_error_strings@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_config@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_get_error@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `X509_NAME_get_text_by_NID@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_write@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_use_PrivateKey_file@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `X509_STORE_load_locations@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `X509_free@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_free@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_ctrl@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_set_ex_data@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_set_verify@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `ENGINE_init@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_set_fd@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/home/jeremy/sourceBuild/gdal-1.11.2/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `sqlite3_column_table_name'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_read@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `ERR_reason_error_string@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_connect@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_ctrl@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_use_PrivateKey@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `X509_STORE_set_flags@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_pending@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `ENGINE_finish@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `ENGINE_load_private_key@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_library_init@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `X509_get_subject_name@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_set_id_callback@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_shutdown@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `SSL_get_peer_certificate@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [gdalinfo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jeremy/sourceBuild/gdal-1.11.2/apps'
make: *** [apps-target] Error 2
```

UPDATE: I created a virtual machine from a new Ubuntu 14.04 iso, and building from source there didn't give me any trouble. I'm beginning to wonder if it has something to do with my Anaconda installation, since this is the only reference to SSL in my config.log:

```
/home/jeremy/anaconda3/lib/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `SSLv2_client_method'
```

Comment: I have the same problem on my ubuntu 14.04 machine....

Comment: have you installed libssl-dev? and did you tell config where openssl is installed?

Comment: try ubuntugis-unstable channel sudo sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable

Comment: @iant I have libssl-dev up to date (`sudo apt-get install libssl-dev` returns that it's already up to date). I'm not sure how to tell config where openssl is installed in this case, as I don't see references to it in the config files I've looked at. Any tips?

Comment: @nickves I added the unstable ppa, and that did get me a newer gdal, but still no python scripts in usr/bin.

Comment: @JeremyG. Did you install the GDAL python bindings or just GDAL? `sudo apt-get install python-gdal`

Comment: @Luke That's exactly it! I didn't know that the bindings were separate, I always saw that they were bundled with gdal. Now I've got the python scripts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to build from source to get a recent GDAL installed on Ubuntu.  Don't bother with the UbuntuGIS-Stable PPA, use [UbuntuGIS-Unstable](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable).  Unstable in this case does not mean buggy and shouldn't be used, it just means it is updated more frequently.  The UbuntuGIS Stable PPA has not even been updated for the most recent Ubuntu LTS (14.04) which was released nearly a year ago...

Once you have added the unstable PPA, you need to install the gdal binaries AND the gdal python bindings:

```
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin python-gdal
```

To answer your question as asked... An easy way to get all the build dependencies for gdal if you *really* need to build from source, (i.e. if you need to modify the build to include ECW or other proprietary format support) is to add the unstable PPA, then install build dependencies via apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep gdal
```

Comment: Installing both binaries from UbuntuGIS-Unstable worked for me. Thank you!  

Not sure if this should be a separate thing, but I haven't seen it anywhere else, so here goes. I got gdal2tiles.py running, but in order to get it working, I had to replace 900913 with 3857 in the script. At least on my machine, the script couldn't load EPSG 900913, but as indicated by MappaGnosis' comment here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34276/whats-the-difference-between-epsg4326-and-epsg900913, 3857 is the current code for the artist formerly known as EPSG:900913.

Answer (score 1):

I had more versions of libsqlite3 due to my anaconda installation. Deleting anaconda dir from my path and re-running ./configure solved my problem.

Comment: This solved my problem. SD

Answer (score -1):

Do this:

```
apt-get install g++ php5-dev libgdal1-dev git
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/geonef/php5-gdal.git && cd php5-gdal
phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

An then open gdal.ini like that:(it will be created)

```
sudo nano/etc/php5/mods-available/gdal.ini
```

and paste this code:

```
; configuration for GDAL module
extension=gdal.so
```

Save it with CTRL + X. Then:

```
sudo php5enmod gdal
service apache2 restart
```

And then you done!