# install GDAL 2.0 on Ubuntu 14

Tags: gdal, python-3

I would like to install `GDAL==2.0.1` on Ubuntu. A lot of possibilities are found on SO, but none did work for me. I'll give an overview of a selection of my attempts:

**1. Using pip directly**

```
pip install gdal==2.0.1
```

returns:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-xob38erk/gdal/

Note: `ez_setup` and `setup_tools` are [installed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36025294/5316326)

**2. [easy_install](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/)**

```
easy_install GDAL==2.0.1
```

returns:

> setuptools.sandbox.UnpickleableException:
>
> gdal_config_error(FileNotFoundError(2, "No such file or directory: 'gdal-config'"),)

**3. [Build from source](https://milkator.wordpress.com/2014/05/06/set-up-gdal-on-ubuntu-14-04/)**

Set variables

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-all-dev
export BASE=~
export GDALVERSION='2.0.1'
```

derive a few others

```
export GDALFILE="gdal-${GDALVERSION}.tar.gz "
export GDALURL="http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/${GDALVERSION}/${GDALFILE}"
export GDALDIR="$BASE/gdal-${GDALVERSION}"
```

Download, install and compile for Python

```
cd $BASE
wget $GDALURL
tar -xvzf $GDALFILE
cd $GDALDIR
./configure --with-python
make
sudo make install
```

I get the same [error as described by Jeremy G.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/138629/60310)

**4. [install Python-Gdal](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/138934/60310)**

```
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin python-gdal
```

This runs with success, but no package `gdal` is known (with `import gdal` in python shell or `pip freeze`).

Comment: As I know the gdal 2 are only available from ubuntugis-unstable ppa (https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable) and nextgis ppa (https://launchpad.net/~nextgis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages). There are you get it?

Comment: This instruction based on ubuntugis stable. GDAL 1.11.2 is only there. Instead sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa && sudo apt-get update you have to execute sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable && sudo apt-get update to get GDAL 2

Comment: This runs successfully, thanks. But still I do not have `gdal` as a package

Comment: How do you check it? I usually do: from osgeo import gdal and than print gdal.__version__. Also check ls /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osgeo/ or ls /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/osgeo/ - they should exists

Comment: just like that, or with `pip freeze` in ubuntu shell

Comment: if I run `sudo apt-get install python-gdal` I get `python-gdal is already the newest version.`